# How to fetch last row data from table using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have used this below code to get all row from table but I wanted only last row data

```
WebElement webtable=driver.findElement(By.id("requisitionsTable")); 

List <WebElement> rowCollection=webtable.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='requisitionsTable']/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("No. of Rows in the WebTable: "+rowCollection.size());


for(WebElement rowElement:rowCollection)
{
    System.out.println("rowElement"+rowElement.getText());
      List<WebElement> colCollection=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));

      for(WebElement colElement:colCollection)
      {
           System.out.print(colElement.getText());
           System.out.print(" ");

       } 
      System.out.println("");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below cssSelector to get the last row data.

```
By lastRow=By.cssSelector("table#requisitionsTable tr:last-child");

driver.findElement(lastRow).getText();
```

Comment: Hi Santosh I tried above code but was getting error "locators not found" So i tried int rowSize = rowCollection.size();
  System.out.println(rowSize);
  By lastRow=By.xpath("//*[@id='requisitionsTable']/tbody/tr["+rowSize+"]");
  System.out.println("last row "+driver.findElement(lastRow).getText());
 and got output

Comment: One more issue is there that we are using pagination so its fetching last row of first page only its not going to the second page

Comment: You are welcome. but, above logic should work fine in getting last row data in first page.

Comment: I have tried like By lastRow=By.cssSelector("table#requisitionsTable tr:10"); or int rowSize = rowCollection.size(); By lastRow=By.cssSelector("table#requisitionsTable tr:rowSize ");  but then also not got